# Android: how to get the views of a Fragment

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-fragments

In a class i am adding a Fragment programatically.

This Fragment contains a Button, which i want to have an onClick implementation.

Here is the class i have:

```
public class ShareProduct extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.share_product);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();

        ProductFragment1 fragment = new ProductFragment1();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.share_product_parent, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        Button done_button = (Button) fragment.getView().findViewById(
                R.id.done_product_1);
        done_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                ProductFragment2 fragment = new ProductFragment2();
                fragmentTransaction
                        .replace(R.id.share_product_parent, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and my ProductFragment1 class is:

```
public class ProductFragment1 extends SherlockFragment {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.share_product_1, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

and the layout my main class uses is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/share_product_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the layout my ProductFragment1 uses is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv1"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done_product_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/et1"
        android:text="Done" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The problem is:**

I am getting a NullPointerException at this line in my main class:

```
Button done_button = (Button) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.done_product_1);
done_button.setOnClickListener ....
```

when i searched for what `getView()` on a fragment returns. I found out that it returns the view from `onCreateView();`

I checked it doesn't return null.

Thank You

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are on the wrong track here. You get the `NPE` because the `Fragments` views is not created yet. `Fragments` also have a lifecycle just like `Activities`.

What you should be doing is assigning the `OnClickListener` inside your `Fragments` `onViewCreated()` method. And from there... you should create a callback and notify your hosting `Activity` of the event.